# Regular Expression to Select Particular Text

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
<b>Dummy Alerts: </b>3/3Alerts have been addressed&#10; Question Alert: Have you had problems or are your volumes lower than normal?  " +
            "Yes Alert is closed on 01/09/2018 at 01:08 PM&#10; Question Alert: Have you been drinking more fluid? " +
            " Yes Alert is closed on 10/09/2019 at 01:08 PM&#10;&#10;Ram support visit performed 10/9/17,  Weight 90.2kg (dry). " +
            "TW achieved. No peripheral edema. BP within routine range per patient history. Urine output 1050ml. No PO fluid restriction at this time. " +
            "Patient did forget to bring in flow sheets.  Monitor UF trend with flow sheet review in one week. Michelle Mayhew Smith, RN."
```

**And i have similar type of many records.**

> I want to select:-

```
 Ram support visit performed 10/9/17,  Weight 90.2kg (dry).
            TW achieved. No peripheral edema. BP within routine range per patient history. Urine output 1050ml. No PO fluid restriction at this time.
            Patient did forget to bring in flow sheets.Monitor UF trend with flow sheet review in one week. Michelle Mayhew Smith, RN.
```

**Using Regular expression in C#.**

> Can you please help.?

Comment: Why not use a library intended for parsing HTML, such as HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: Or split by `&#10;`?

Comment: Can you please explain.. or give some example..?

Comment: @Rafalon:- If you see the text .. there's multiple `&#10;` text  and also `+` symbol there. How to avoid those `+` symbol from whole text and how to select  for particular `&#10;`. ?

Comment: Well you apparently need the text *after* the last `&#10;`. If so, check my answer below

Comment: Concerning the `+` symbol, just note that `"bla" + "bla"` is the same as `"blabla"`. All `+` does is concatenate those strings together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string dummyString = "<b>Dummy Alerts: </b>3/3Alerts have been addressed&#10; Question Alert: Have you had problems or are your volumes lower than normal?  " +
            "Yes Alert is closed on 01/09/2018 at 01:08 PM&#10; Question Alert: Have you been drinking more fluid? " +
            " Yes Alert is closed on 10/09/2019 at 01:08 PM&#10;&#10;Ram support visit performed 10/9/17,  Weight 90.2kg (dry). " +
            "TW achieved. No peripheral edema. BP within routine range per patient history. Urine output 1050ml. No PO fluid restriction at this time. " +
            "Patient did forget to bring in flow sheets.  Monitor UF trend with flow sheet review in one week. Michelle Mayhew Smith, RN.";

        // With String.Split    
        var splitted = dummyString.Split(new string[]{"&#10;"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        Console.WriteLine(splitted[splitted.Length-1]);

        // With String.LastIndexOf & String.Substring
        int lastIndex = dummyString.LastIndexOf("&#10;");
        Console.WriteLine(dummyString.Substring(lastIndex+5));
    }
}
```

Writes twice:

> Ram support visit performed 10/9/17,  Weight 90.2kg (dry). TW achieved. No peripheral edema. BP within routine range per patient history. Urine output 1050ml. No PO fluid restriction at this time. Patient did forget to bring in flow sheets.  Monitor UF trend with flow sheet review in one week. Michelle Mayhew Smith, RN.